# Kinect SDK :Problems with tracking skeleton and drawing them using OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm using the Kinect for Windows SDK to extract the skeleton and color image, and then draw the skeleton points on the color image each frame. I use `cvCircle()` function in OpenCV to draw the extracted skeleton points on the kinect color image(converted to `IplImage`).

When I wave my hand, the skeleton point corresponding to the waving hand is drifting away from the real position that skeleton point should be. But this situation did not happen in the Sample:"Kinect Explorer-D2D" .

I'll post my code. My code is imitating the SDK sample:"Skeleton Basics-D2D". The difference is I use Console Application while the sample is Windows Application(I'm unfamiliar with Windows Application) and I add kinect color image stream.

```
IplImage *frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), 8, 3);
HRESULT hr;
hr = NuiInitialize(NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_SKELETON | NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_COLOR);

if(hr != S_OK)
    return hr;

HANDLE SkeletonEvent = CreateEventW(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
hr = NuiSkeletonTrackingEnable(SkeletonEvent, 0);
if(hr != S_OK)
    return hr;

HANDLE ColorEvent = CreateEventW(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
HANDLE h2 = NULL;
hr = NuiImageStreamOpen(NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_COLOR, NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480, 0, 2, ColorEvent, &h2);
if(hr != S_OK)
    return hr;

NUI_SKELETON_FRAME skeletonFrame = {0};
while(1){
    WaitForSingleObject(SkeletonEvent, INFINITE);
    //get skeleton data
    hr = NuiSkeletonGetNextFrame(0, &skeletonFrame);
    if( hr != S_OK )
        continue;
    NuiTransformSmooth(&skeletonFrame, NULL);
    //get color image data
    const NUI_IMAGE_FRAME * pImageFrame = NULL;
    hr = NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame(h2, 0, &pImageFrame );
    if( hr != S_OK )
        continue;

    INuiFrameTexture *pTexture = pImageFrame->pFrameTexture;
    NUI_LOCKED_RECT LockedRect;
    pTexture->LockRect( 0, &LockedRect, NULL, 0 );
    //Convert the color image to IplImage frame
    if(LockedRect.Pitch != 0)
        ConvertDataToIplImage(LockedRect, frame);
    //Draw skeleton points on frame     
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        NUI_SKELETON_TRACKING_STATE trackingState = skeletonFrame.SkeletonData[i].eTrackingState;
        if (NUI_SKELETON_TRACKED == trackingState)
            for(int j=0; j<20; j++)
                cvCircle(frame,   
                         SkeletonToScreen(skeletonFrame.SkeletonData[i].SkeletonPositions[j],640, 480,pImageFrame),
                         4, CV_RGB(255,0,0),2);

    }
    cvShowImage("Frame",frame);
    NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame( h2, pImageFrame );
    cvWaitKey(30);
}
```

The function `SkeletonToScreen()` is:

```
 CvPoint SkeletonToScreen(Vector4 skeletonPoint, int width, int height, const
NUI_IMAGE_FRAME *imgFrame)
{
LONG x, y;
USHORT depth;
LONG ColorX, ColorY;
NuiTransformSkeletonToDepthImage(skeletonPoint, &x, &y, &depth);
NuiImageGetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixelAtResolution(NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480,
                                                NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_320x240,
                                                &imgFrame->ViewArea,
                                                x,
                                                y,
                                                depth,
                                                &ColorX,
                                                &ColorY);
float screenPointX = static_cast<float>(ColorX * width) / 640;
float screenPointY = static_cast<float>(ColorY * height) / 480; 
return cvPoint(screenPointX, screenPointY);
}
```

My result is http://www.dropbox.com/s/d0kudegrnecklel/my%20result.jpg. 
The Skeleton Basics-D2D result is http://www.dropbox.com/s/y9rvvoxijv4rs28/the%20kinect%20explorer.jpg.

We see when hand waving fast, the Skeleton Basics-D2D track the skeleton points well, but my skeleton points are away from my hand and wrist.

Comment: Don't use the depricated C bindings of c++. It will make it much, much easier to debug.

Comment: Hi, @Nallath ,I'm not getting distinctly to the "deprecated C bindings of c++", Did my code use this form?

Comment: Yeah; IplImage for instance is the old c style. The c++ part of opencv uses cv::Mat, which is far easier to use.